# Error - RaceOnRCWCleanup was detected during Parallel.Invoke method

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am trying to export all sheets of an Excel file using following piece of code. I am calling one method using different values of parameters.

It is giving me following error on ExecuteNonQuery of one of the Sheet() method.

> RaceOnRCWCleanup was detected
>   An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use.  The RCW is in use on the active thread or another thread.  Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause corruption or data loss.

Is this operation possible? If yes, please give me a hint or solution which I will try in my code

```
Action[] actionsArray = new Action[]
{
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet1",dataTable1),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet2",dataTable2),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet3",dataTable3),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet4",dataTable4),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet5",dataTable5),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet6",dataTable6),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet7",dataTable7),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet8",dataTable8),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet9",dataTable9),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet10",dataTable10),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet11",dataTable11),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet12",dataTable12),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet13",dataTable13),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet14",dataTable14),
    () => InsertDataToExcelSheet(oleDBcmd,"sheet15",dataTable15)
};

Parallel.Invoke(actionsArray);

private static object InsertDataToExcelSheet(OleDbCommand cmd, string sheet, DataTable dt)
{            
    sheet = sheet.Replace(".", "#");
    switch (sheet)
    {
        case "Sheet1":
            Sheet1(cmd, dt, sheet);
            break;
        case "Sheet2":
            Sheet2(cmd, dt, sheet);
            break;
        case "Sheet3":
            Sheet3(cmd, dt, sheet);
            break;

    }
}   

//sheet1,sheet2 ans sheet3 methods are like follows
 private static void Sheet1(OleDbCommand cmd, DataTable dt, string sheet)
{
    int rowNum = 3;
    foreach (DataRowView row in dt)
    {

        string InsertQuery = @"Insert Into [" + sheet + "$A" + rowNum + ":D" + rowNum + "]" +
                            " Values('" + row[0] + "','" + row[1] + "','" + row[2] + "','" +
                                          row[3] + "');";


        cmd.CommandText = InsertQuery;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        rowNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is basically telling you that using a single OleDbCommand object on multiple threads is not safe.  Very little point to it, Excel itself serializes access to its data so it isn't going to get any faster with Parallel.Invoke().

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write data to excel file in a faster way. I am using **SSIS** now and it is really efficient. Thanks you for help.